# How am i able to display text in html according to the video that is being played randomly?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have text displayed according to the video played randomly and the text will be assigned to that specific video and if that video is played then only that specific text which is assigned to the video should show up.

```js
var videos = [{
    id: 1,
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/k47u9tduwb8?autoplay=1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/lJ6osaYFSIA?autoplay=1"
  }
];

window.onload = function() {
  var playerDiv = document.getElementById("random_player");
  var player = document.createElement("IFRAME");
  var previousId = localStorage.getItem('previousId');
  if (previousId) {
    var previousIndex = videos.findIndex(v => v.id === parseInt(previousId));
    videos.splice(previousIndex, 1);
  }
  var current = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
  localStorage.setItem('previousId', videos[current].id);
  localStorage.getItem('previousId');
  var randomVideoUrl = videos[current].url;
  player.setAttribute('width', '640');
  player.setAttribute('height', '390');
  player.setAttribute('src', randomVideoUrl);
  playerDiv.appendChild(player);
};
```

```html
<div id="random_player"></div>
```

Comment: this is hard to achieve without Jquery.

Comment: https://codepen.io/icutpeople/pen/whueK prefer this working example, might be helpfull

Comment: Beautiful thank you soo much omer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Full Example working](https://codepen.io/Hassuunna/pen/YzKjdrm)**

*Explanation*

**First of all** `div` tag is not self closing tag, means you have to write `</div>` to close it

*Correct*

```
<div> content </div>
```

*Wrong*

```
<div/> content
```

**second:** you just need a container to embed the text in based on the specific ( i.e current ) video you're playing

```
   var textContainer = document.getElementById("text");
   textContainer.innerHTML = videos[current].text;
```

**Finally** just add more property to your videos objects with text for every URL and based on current value embed it in your html

```
    var videos = [ { id:1, URL: '...', text: '...' },...]
```

Comment: Thank you i will give it a go and about the tags i think i messed it up while i was copying and pasting it.

Comment: It works perfectly i really appreciate the help am i also able to display the text ontop of the video being played aswell? as like a text overlay for the video?

Comment: Yes you can, I just edited the above example on Codepen, as you can see it's matter of some CSS, no big deal

* I know this is not responsive but you got the point on how to make the overlaying text

Comment: i just tried the updated one but unfortunately it's not working for me

Comment: In my code i even <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" /> linked it in my <head> and still getting no results as you are getting on that page

Comment: check the console in browser to make sure your CSS file is linked properly and if error appears please paste it here

Answer (score 0):

make sure to run the code in your browser

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Insert HTML inside an iFrame</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  background: #333;
}
.video-container {
  position: relative;
}
iframe {
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
.overlay-desc {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Nobile', sans-serif;
  font-size: 9vw;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}

p {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  line-height: 1.7rem;
}
 
</style>

<script>
      var videos = [
        {id:1 , url:"https://www.youtube.com/embed/k47u9tduwb8?autoplay=1"},
        {id:2 , url:"https://www.youtube.com/embed/lJ6osaYFSIA?autoplay=1"}      
      ];

      window.onload = function () {
     //  document.getElementById('myIframe').src = videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];

    /*
          var player = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
    var sources = player.getElementsByTagName('source');
   
   sources[0].src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/lJ6osaYFSIA?autoplay=1';
   player.load(); */
   
    var playerDiv = document.getElementById("video-container");
        var player = document.createElement("IFRAME");
      /*  var previousId = localStorage.getItem('previousId');
        if(previousId) {
          var previousIndex = videos.findIndex(v => v.id === parseInt(previousId));
          videos.splice(previousIndex, 1);
        }
    
        localStorage.setItem('previousId', videos[current].id);
        localStorage.getItem('previousId');
        */
            var current = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
        var randomVideoUrl = videos[current].url;
        player.setAttribute('width', '640');
        player.setAttribute('height', '390');
        player.setAttribute('src', randomVideoUrl);
  console.log(player)
        playerDiv.appendChild(player);
  }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nobile:700,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gafata|Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div id="video-container" class="video-container">
 <!--   <video id="video" autoplay loop muted>
       <source id="source" src="http://www.icutpeople.com/wp-content/themes/icutpeople/assets/video/waynesworld.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video> -->
    <!--<iframe id="myIframe" ></iframe> -->

    
     <div class="overlay-desc">
        <h1>Video Title</h1>
     </div>
 </div>





</body>
</html>
```